Have you tried Comodo antivirus (ubuntu 24.04)
Last days I ran ClamTK and discovered a virus:
PUA.Win.Trojan.Xored-1
Got a few time this virus-PUA and ClamAV did not detect it, but not real time APP.
My question is about Comodo AV APP for Linux (free), have you tried?
Thanks
serros

This is a related question.

Yes, I tried all of them. And NONE of them add any value unless you sent what your scan to Windows machines in your network (in this setup Ubuntu acts as a gateway). All clam is is a waste of CPU cycles and more than often it is a scam trying to get you to hand over money for a license you do not need.

Last days I ran ClamTK and discovered a virus: PUA.Win.Trojan.Xored-1

As with all of these notices on Linux: that is a false positive. See https://github.com/jensyt/imurmurhash-js/issues/1
All these tools use Windows as their base for finding pieces of code that a virus uses. But that bit of code can also be part of a legitimate piece of software. Using it still triggers this virus warning.
As said before: Currently there is NO virus in the wild that can infect all our systems as what can happen in Windows. For us to get a virus we need to install it ourself. And as we only install from Ubuntu repositories that are virus free we don't get any.
So: keep the system updated, don't install random software or software you do not use, disable services you do not use and there is nothing to worry about.
If you use a system that hosts a webservices and databases the main issue to focus on are rootkits.

Thanks, I just discover:
Real-Time Scanning:
Using inotify or fswatch, you can set up ClamAV to monitor files and directories for changes, and trigger an immediate scan.
Alternatively, clamd (ClamAV's daemon) can run in the background and scan files as they are accessed by the system.
clamav-unofficial-sigs (the tool you mentioned earlier) can be used to keep ClamAV’s signatures updated with extra threat definitions.
Do you know?

Do you mean this?
https://www.comodo.com/home/download/download.php?prod=antivirus-for-linux
I do seem to remember using it back when it was still supported. Looking at that site the release suggest it has not been updated since 2013 and the version of Ubuntu listed is 12.04. I very strongly suspect it will not run on later versions.
If memory serves it was more slick that Clamtk but did give a lot of false positives in a similar way to Clam. (See other answers.)
I keep Clamtk on my rig as I have quite a few WINE application installs and I like to think it might be useful scanning these.

Researchers Discover "Bootkitty" – First UEFI Bootkit Targeting Linux Kernels.
https://thehackernews.com/2024/11/researchers-discover-bootkitty-first.html
Cybersecurity researchers have shed light on what has been described as the first Unified Extensible Firmware Interface (UEFI) bootkit designed for Linux systems.
Dubbed Bootkitty by its creators who go by the name BlackCat, the bootkit is assessed to be a proof-of-concept (PoC) and there is no evidence that it has been put to use in real-world attacks. Also tracked as IranuKit, it was uploaded to the VirusTotal platform November 5, 24.
